# Call helm on region

Tags: helm, region

I just found out about [helm-surfraw](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html#orgheadline25) by reading Tuhdo's Helm guide.

For those familiar with Helm, is there a way for me to call `helm-surfraw` on a selected region, i.e., using the region as the input for helm?

Example, let's say I'm writing a text and I want to find a synonym for a word. Instead of calling `helm-surfraw`, typing the word and searching, I'd like to mark the word and have helm automatically take it as an input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With latest version of Helm (see [this PR](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/pull/2002)), if you select a region before calling `helm-surfraw`, the text in the region will be used as the "default" argument. Saying you have selected "hello world" then typing

```
M-x helm-surfraw RET RET google RET
```

will Google "hello world". You can also use <kbd>M-n</kbd> (`next-history-element`) to put the default argument to minibuffer so that you can change it if you want.